# production settings for django project

Tags: python, django, heroku, production

I have created a `production_settings.py` in which I am putting all the production env variables and values eg:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

I thought I'd declare an env variable like

MYPROJECT_PRODUCTION

and set this like

`heroku config:add MYPROJECT_PRODUCTION=True` or `export MYPROJECT_PRODUCTION=True`

In the settings.py (which is the default created by django) ,I thought I'd add at the end of the file

```
import os
if os.environ.has_key('MYPROJECT_PRODUCTION') and os.environ.get('MYPROJECT_PRODUCTION')=='True':
    from production_settings import *
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?

I am getting an import error when I try `python manage shell`

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='myproject.settings'
export MYPROJECT_PRODUCTION=True
me@ubuntu:~/dev/python/django/myproject$ python manage.py shell
Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'manage.py'. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)
```

the manage.py exists in the same folder as settings.py ..still the error occurs.

I  checked `echo $MYPROJECT_PRODUCTION` which outputs `True`

Comment: added the Heroku tag, because for me your solution seems fine, maybe somebody else using django on heroku can answer your question.

Comment: Can you print the dir structure of your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I keep my production settings in `settings.py` then include a `local_settings.py` file (that's excluded from revision control with .hgignore).

I add the following to the end of settings.py

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError, e:
    pass
```

Then in my local_settings.py I override the appropriate settings -

```
DEBUG = True

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'tag',
        'USER': 'tag',
        'PASSWORD': 'tag',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I'm under the impression that this is a fairly well used method (I picked it up from colleagues but I've seen it blogged about too)

EDIT

In response to balazs very good point you might include a variation on this method, in order to keep sensitive data private. Perhaps include the following after the `local_settings` import -

```
try:
    from production_settings import *
except ImportError, e:
    pass
```

Then exclude `production_settings.py` from version control. I guess you may need to use a different method to deploy `production_settings.py`, but I don't suppose that's too big a deal.

Comment: what @damon uses is also a common method.I think it's better,because if you use revision control the server settings (with all your sensitive passwords,secret key,etc) file won't go to the repository,which is a good idea if it's public repo,or not you are the only one working on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I advise against using different settings files for different environments in favour of customising your settings with environment variables. This allows you by default to use your local development settings and override it in production.

For example database and static / media root settings

```
# Default database URL is a local SQLite instance
DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///%s' % os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'db.sqlite')

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config('DATABASE_URL', default=DATABASE_URL),
}

MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get('MEDIA_ROOT',
                            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media'))

MEDIA_URL = os.environ.get('MEDIA_URL', '/media/')


STATIC_ROOT = os.environ.get('STATIC_ROOT',
                             os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'))

STATIC_URL = os.environ.get('STATIC_URL', '/static/')
```

This allows you to set any setting on Heroku via `heroku config:set` and removes the complexity of dealing with multiple settings files, for example:

```
heroku config:set MEDIA_URL=http://custom-media-server.com/media/
heroku config:set STATIC_URL=http://custom-media-server.com/static/
```

I have also created a custom [Django project template](https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-project-template) that can take most settings from environment variables.

You should also look at the [12 Factor Application](http://www.12factor.net/) website and specifically at how to [store configuration](http://www.12factor.net/config).

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined DATABASES as a dictionary? by:

```
DATABASES = {}
```

also show your   `heroku logs`